# I am getting wrong data in saved file after scraping data in python

Tags: python

i am a beginner in python programming. i wanted to extract all h1, h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 headings from  container i did it so but i am getting problem in saving that data in csv format.

when i try to save using pandas it shows me this saved csv file.

here it is my code::

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.nidm.net/home/weather/best-air-purifiers/'
target = requests.get(url) #sends the requests to the website
status = target.status_code #checks the status of website
print(status) #prints the status code,, it should be 200

text_response = target.text #basically downloads the website into our 
machine
#print(text_response) #prints the website in console

#now beautiful soup will come in handy to print the results more 
effectively
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text_response, 'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify()) #it will make data more understandable

h1 = ""
h2 = ""
h3 = ""
h4 = ""
h5 = ""
h6 = ""

all_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'jeg_inner_content'})

for _h1 in all_div.find_all('h1'):
   h1 = _h1.text
   print(h1, sep='\n')

for _h2 in all_div.find_all('h2'):
   h2 = _h2.text
   print(h2, sep='\n')

for _h3 in all_div.find_all('h3'):
   h3 = _h3.text
   print(h3, sep='\n')

for _h4 in all_div.find_all('h4'):
   h4 = _h4.text
   print(h4, sep='\n')

for _h5 in all_div.find_all('h5'):
   h5 = _h5.text
   print(h5, sep='\n')

for _h6 in all_div.find_all('h6'):
   h6 = _h6.text
   print(h6, sep='\n')

headings = h1 + '\n' + h2 + '\n' + h3 + '\n' + h4 + '\n' + h5 + '\n' + h6
print(headings)

df = pd.DataFrame({h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6})
df.to_csv('Data1.csv', index=True)

#file = open('data1.txt', 'w+')
#file.write(headings)
#file.close()
```

now the problem is that it is not showing me the right results in my csv file that i want to see. instead it shows me just h1 heading.. please help me..............

Comment: you are extracting last text from all  `h1, h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` heading tags.

Comment: if you want to extract all text from `h1, h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 headings` tags, use list instend of h1,h2.. variable.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here seems to be that you are overwriting your 'heading' variables in each iteration of the *find_all* loops. It could be fixed like that (assuming you want to separate the lines with line breaks):

```
for _h1 in all_div.find_all('h1'):
   h1 = h1 + ('\n' + _h1.text if h1 else _h1.text)   # <-- 
   print(h1, sep='\n')

# do the same for the remaining loops
```

Also, in the DataFrame declaration is worth to note that you are using a set to define the data. This implies that the order of the rows it's not guaranteed. It would be better to use a tuple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6))  # changed {...} to (...)
```

Regarding to the lack of results, note that h4, h5 and h6 don't have any result in the searching scope.